# Random function in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json file with questions, so an array. I want to make all the questions to be random. This is my code from the js file, but I don't know why doesn't work.

```
$http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
        $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
        $scope.myQuestions = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    });
```

And in the html

`<div ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
<p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}}</p></div>`

Comment: `$scope.myQuestions` same name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use:**

```
$scope.randomQuestion= $scope.myQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.myQuestions.length)];
```

And in view:
**{{randomQuestion}}**

**UPDATE:**

```
$http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
        $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
        $scope.randomQuestion= $scope.myQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.myQuestions.length)];  
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
<p class="txt">{{randomQuestion.question}}</p></div>
```

**FINAL UPDATE:**

So, the actual question was not randomizing rather shuffling the questions:

**In your js file:**

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    var m = array.length,
        t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle
    while (m) {
        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }

    return array;
}

// access the http service
// quizData object = data from quiz_data.json
$http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData) {
    $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
    $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
    shuffleArray($scope.myQuestions);
});
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
    <p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}} </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: I put that in my view but doesn't work `ng-repeat="myQuestion in randomQuestion"`

Comment: you don't repeat in randomQuestion. you just show the random question. for e.g: ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions" which will repeat all your questions. if you show {{myQuestion.question}}. just replace that with {{randomQuestion}}

Comment: After I replaced what you told me, on screen I get `{"question":"Saturn is visible from Earth without a telescope"}` instead of just `Saturn is visible from Earth without a telescope`. Something is not right Alex

Comment: i will edit so that it matches your logic. you just need to add .question since it has key value pair. Its really simple when you get question embedded in key value paired json format. Just use . operator to get the question :). See the update in my answer. Anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: Alex random doesn't do anything. Is printing the question text ok on screen but I don't see the power of random at all. I can put it on a live server so you can see it if you want.

Comment: ok, that should have been the first step while asking question :) sure

Comment: This is the link of quiz with your modifications as well [link](http://aproapetot.ro/quiz-angularjs/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104895/discussion-between-alex-rumba-nicked-and-dragon).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$scope.myQuestions = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
```

Overwrites your array of questions and turns it into a random number. I think you want to access it as an array with that number like so:

```
$http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
        $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
        console.log($scope.myQuestions[randomNum]);
    });
```

Comment: we did answer the same thing, at the same time. Now, that i can see it. Our initial answer is actually the same. Keep up the good work. upvoted you :)

Comment: Thanks!  Although yours is clearly the superior answer :p upvoted you too